# C++ passing a structure to a function

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to pass a structure to my function but I can't figure it out. I have the code below

```
struct box
{
char sMaker[40]; 
float fHeight;  //The height of the box
float fWidth;   //The width of the box
float fLength;  //The length of the box
float fVolume;  //The volume of the box
}; //end box

void calcVolume (box *p)
{
p‐>fVolume = p‐>fWidth * p‐>fHeight * p->fLength;
} //end calcVolume
```

It returns the error that p‐ is an undeclared identifier. I'm really new to c++ why's it not compiling.

Thank you so much.

Comment: That code is correct AFAICT, though you might want a reference, doubles, and a `std::string`.

Comment: If this is supposed to be C++ OOP, I'd also make it a class with a member function that returns the volume. I'd also get rid of the Hungarian notation. Blech.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at one of your dashes (`-`) using `emacs`'s `describe-char`:

```
preferred charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x2010
name: HYPHEN
general-category: Pd (Punctuation, Dash)
```

Replace them all with a minus sign.

Comment: +1 For detailed description. I'd just like to add the output of gcc: http://ideone.com/vVa6Nw

Comment: for some reason when i typed the exact same calculation above the one i had, it worked. I guess its some bug in visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your source file is plain ASCII. It seems to me that you are using some extended unicode character in place of the "minus" sign '-'

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably in the code that calls calcVolume (or somewhere else entirely). You need to call it like this:

```
box b;
calcVolume(&b);
```

Edit: Nevermind, the real error is the hyphen (‐) instead of the minus sign (-).